# Stack Spans Vertically Inside Button

Tags: css, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

The following code creates a button in nativescript containing an icon followed by some text. I'd like the button to stack the two spans so that the icon is horizontally centered in the top row of the button, and the text is horizontally centered beneath the icon.

```
<Button>
  <FormattedString>
    <Span fontFamily="IcoMoon-Free" text="{{userPlusIcon}}"></Span>
    <Span text="Create New Account"></Span>
  </FormattedString>
</Button>
```

I'd like the result to look something like the person details button in the following image:
[image]

I've tried using a StackLayout, but you can't nest it inside the button. Also I read in another stack that you can't attach a css class to a Nativescript span. Am I going about this wrong way? Maybe I should use a StackLayout with nested labels instead and put a (tap) event onto the stack to make it act like a button?

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this UI by using a label instead of a button and also using font-awesome icon with the text.Here is the code:

```
<Label row="1" col="0"i[![d="home" text="&#xf015;" (tap)="onChange(0)">
    </Label>
```

[image]